# Dummy form to submit like the real login form

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i have a web application whose login form is in `~/Account/Login.aspx`, where I implemented the login logic and it works as expected.

Now, our graphic designer reshaped the home page putting in a corner a small html login form. I liked the idea of having another login form in the home page, but I don't know how to make this form do submit like the actual login page. I had a look inside the generated html of the real login page but it seems that it doesn't event use a `<form>`, so I can't just adjust the input boxes' names and form action to match the real login's ones.

Is there a way to enable this login form without rewriting all the code behind?

Comment: How is the real form submitted? Using a GET request? Surely, it's using a form to POST the username/password. We can't really say if we don't see the `Login.aspx` markup.

Comment: The problem with that kind of approach is that aspnet abstractize too much. This is the login markup: `<asp:Login ID="formLogin" runat="server" 
LoginButtonText="Submit"
PasswordLabelText="Password"
UserNameLabelText="User Name"
OnAuthenticate="auth_Click"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX to call the membership services in order to authenticate the user:

You would need to enable the `AuthenticationServices` in the web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCaching="false" enableCompression="false" />
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="false" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

And then in a page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:LoginView runat="server">
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <input type="tel" name="user" id="user" />
            <br />
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Login" name="login" id="login" onclick="attemptLogin(this);" />
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <input type="button" name="logout" id="logout" value="Logout" onclick="attemptLogout(this);" />
        </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
    <asp:LoginName FormatString="Welcome {0}!" runat="server" />
    <%--<asp:LoginStatus runat="server" />--%>
</div>
    <script>
        function attemptLogin(e) {
            Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.login(
                $get("user").value,
                $get("pass").value,
                false,
                null,
                null,
                function success(validCredentials, userContext, methodName) {
                    if (validCredentials == true) {
                        alert("user logged in");
                        window.location = window.location;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("user name or password incorrect");
                    }
                }, function fail(error, userContext, methodName) {
                    alert(error.get_message());
                }, null);
        }

        function attemptLogout(e) {
            Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.logout(
                window.location,
                null,
                null,
                null
            );
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could expose a web service with the login logic and call that web service instead of the `AuthenticationService` using AJAX

Another way would be to create a `UserControl` with the login controls and put that control on the home page handling the login events in the `UserControl`'s code behind

Comment: If I try to login it says: "An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax". Could be related to the fact that I'm using Forms Authentication?

Comment: Most likely you need to configure your membership section in your web.config file. I just uploaded this sample to my GitHub site [Web.config](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Web.config) and [the ASPX page](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/Membership/ScriptServices/LoginUsingScriptServices.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using any role/membership provider

Comment: Could u kindly take a look at the my question and suggest if I can resolve it with your approach, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009246/authenticate-web-user-in-background-dua-iframe#comment28084671_19009246